# Unable to fetch the specific entire XML tag by using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, dom

I have the below sample XML file

Sample XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
    <class name="com.transfermoney.Transfer">
        <test-method status="PASS" name="setParameter" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
            <params>
                <param index="0">
                    <value>                   
                          <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                    </value>
                </param>
            </params>
            <reporter-output>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->
     </class>
     <class name="com.transfermoney.Transfer">
        <test-method status="FAIL" name="setSettlementFlag" is-config="true" duration-ms="5"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z">
            <reporter-output>
                <line>                                                             
                       <![CDATA[runSettlement Value Set :false]]>
                </line>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> setSettlementFlag
    </class> 
</testng-results>
```

I just want to take the below piece of tags from above XML file based on status PASS (I don't want to take `<?XML version`, `<testng-results>` and `class` tags those are should be ignored).

**Expected Output:**

```
   <test-method status="PASS" name="setParameter" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
            <params>
                <param index="0">
                    <value>                   
                          <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                    </value>
                </param>
            </params>
            <reporter-output>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method>
```

I just used below XSLT to get the above output from sample XML file but It doesn't work  It returned all the tags but I just want the above output not other than anything.

XSLT:

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>"
            <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>  
            </xsl:template>
           <xsl:template match="class"/>
           <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
           <xsl:for-each select="test-method[@status='PASS']">
            <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also Using the below java code to run the XSLT and sample XML file

**Code:**

```
    String XML = fetchDataFrmXML(".//Test//testng-results_2.xml");
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSL)));
    t.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(XML)), new StreamResult(new File(".//Test//Sample1.xml")));
```

This is the sample payload. But the actual payload had multiple nodes with "PASS" and "Failed" status. I'm just only interested to fetch the PASS node in the above output format.

Any leads....

Comment: Could you post your XSLT in an unescaped form, so we can test it?

Comment: Sure I will make the changes now

Comment: Updated the XSLT. if there is any issue in the XSLT. please give me some idea about it.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I'm new to the XSLT. Probably the XSLT is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The result you show could be obtained quite simply by doing just:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/testng-results">
    <xsl:copy-of select="class/test-method[@status='PASS']" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

However, in case of more than one `test-method` having a `status` of  `"PASS"` this will result in an XML fragment with no single root element. So you'd probably be better off doing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/testng-results">
    <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="class/test-method[@status='PASS']" />
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It returned only the below tag  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>